# Asymptotic convergence of shifted and scaled Wigner matrix

Tags: probability-theory, probability-limit-theorems, random-matrices

Let $\frac{X}{\sqrt n}$ be a Wigner matrix, such that $X_{ij}$ are iid random variables, with mean 0 and variance 1, with $X_{ij} = \overline{X_{ij}}$ for $i > j$.
Then we know by Wigner's Theorem that the the spectral measure $L_n$ of $\frac{X}{\sqrt n}$ converges weakly to the semicircle law $f(x) = \mathbb{1}_{[-2,2]}(x)\frac{\sqrt{4 - x^2}}{2 \pi }$.

Can anything be said about the convergence of diagonally shifted and scaled Wigner matrices $$W = \sigma \frac{X}{\sqrt n} + a I_n$$ where $\sigma > 0$ and $a \in \mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Hint: If $\mu$ is the spectral measure of $X/\sqrt{n}$, what can you say about the spectral measure of $W$?

Comment: Denoting by $\lambda_i$ the eigenvalues of $\frac{X}{\sqrt n}$ since $Spec(W) = \{\sigma \lambda_i + a\}$, we can do a change of variables to get $\mu_W (x) = \mu (\frac{x-a}{\sigma})$. I'm unsure how to prove the convergence argument though.